# To prevent image cache by adding version: the version as a param or a part of filename?

Tags: css, node.js, caching

Generally the image would full cached by using http header: expire or cache-control,
In order to images on client keep up with server's,
Generally there are two ways:
1.use the md5 as the a part of the name; `e.g.: my.md5.css`
2.change the param: `e.g.: my.css?v=md5`

which one i should to use？how to choose?

Comment: `?v=md5` imo... is it generated on the server? cuz with the first solution you would have to upload the new file with the new name each time you change a style and therefore change the `my.md5.css` to the new name.

Comment: md5 is generated on server. but if rename the file when changed,  the count of file will expand.